# V-model in Vue Instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I have read that "**v-model directives take the data property of Vue instance as the single source of truth as opposed to HTML element attributes**"? I'm kind of a bit confused. Does it mean that in Vue component, only the data binded with v-model will only be taken into consideration when processing data and if there is a value assigned in html attributes, it will not be considered?

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is a two way data binding, which means that the data will change according to the data in the input html tag, and also if you change the data itself - the value you see in the input itself will change as well.

so if you do not use v-model on an input html tag, the data will not change according to it. And best way to access the value of the input is by using `v-model`

Comment: I see. So, it's just another way of explaining how data is updated live according to input in vue. Thank you.